# Symfony : error message at form root with atPath method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form without entity, and I like to validate it with CallBack constraint. But error are setting on the root of the form instead of the form element.

A part of my form :

```
   $builder
      ->add('judgmentPeriod', DatesPeriod::class, [
             'constraints' => new Callback(array(
             'callback' => [$this, 'datesAreEmpty'],
             'groups' => ['insertionPeriod']))
      ])
      ->add('insertionPeriod', DatesPeriod::class, [
             'constraints' => new Callback(array(
             'callback' => [$this, 'datesAreEmpty'],
             'groups' => ['judgmentPeriod']))
      ])
   ;
```

DatesPeriod contains 2 DateTime subforms.

My callback function :

```
public function datesAreEmpty($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if(isset($data['end']) && $data['end'] != null || isset($data['start']) && $data['start'] != null) {
        $context
            ->buildViolation('error.dates_period.not_empty')
            ->atPath('[insertionPeriod]')
            ->addViolation()
        ;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `error.dates_period.not_empty` message is showing on the top of the form and not on the insertionPeriod element ..

I don't really know how works atPath method, but I think I don't provide a correct parameter.

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I found the solution, I had to force error_bubbling to false.

Comment: Have you tried omitting `atPath` call at all? Your constraints are bound to the field itself (and not the form as a whole), so contextually, you are already at that path.

Comment: Yes, i just tried, and it's the same result ..

Comment: I thought that `error_bubbling` was by default set to `FALSE`... hmm...